# Почему компоненты Alpha Controls не отображаются на другом компьютере?

Tags: delphi

Использую в проекте Дельфи компоненты Alpha Controls, все работает. Но когда запускаю экзешник на другом компьютере, эти компоненты не отображают оформление, т.е. форма без скинов. Что делать? подскажите пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в программе программно загрузить скин и давать его вместе с программой.
Когда Вы делаете прогу - указываете на использующиеся скин,а его на другом компьютере нет.

Обязательно грузите его программно, что бы не было ещё неожиданностей.

Comment: А плюсануть??